# Como converter um yaml para array PHP?

Tags: php, array, yaml

Como poderia fazer para converter dados `yaml` em um `array` do PHP?

Exemplo yaml:

```
Usuario:
    nome: Wallace
    idade: 25
    linguagens: 
        - PHP
        - Python
        - Javascript
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No [Manual do PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.yaml-parse.php), tem um exemplo:

```
$yaml = <<<EOD
Usuario:
    nome: Wallace
    idade: 25
    linguagens: 
        - PHP
        - Python
        - Javascript
EOD;

  $parsed = yaml_parse($yaml);

 echo "<pre>";
  print_r($parsed);
```

Só não esqueça de habilitar a extensão: `extension=yaml.so` no `php.ini`

Para instalar: https://code.google.com/p/php-yaml/
Para linux: http://bd808.com/pecl-file_formats-yaml/

Answer (score 5):

Uma boa maneira seria utilizando o `Yaml Component` do `Symphony`.

Veja:

```
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Parser;

$yaml = new Parser();

$value = $yaml->parse(file_get_contents('/arquivo.yml'));
```

Referência: [The Yaml Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml/introduction.html)

Comment: +1 pelo symfony

Comment: Gosto muito do `Symphony`. É uma pena que a maioria dos sistema já estão escritos aqui em `Laravel 4` (que não é ruim também)